# Relative dates in org template

Tags: org-mode

I organize a technical user group and as part of that I use org-mode to schedule the same task tree every month so I remember to do everything for our meetings (food, speakers, projector, etc.) This, to me, sounds like a perfect use case for a capture template. What I'd like to do is specify an event name and date and have the rest of the tasks automatically calculated based on that. Here's the template I have so far (simplified a bit to show what I want to do):

```
("m" "Meetup" (file+headline "~/org/STLPython.org" "events")
 "** %^{Event}\n%^{Date}t\n*** Send a reminder to the group\nSCHEDULED: <%<%^{Date}t -5d>>"))
```

Ideally, I'd get this output, after specifying "Event" and "Date" once each:

```
** Documenting with Sphinx: Beyond Quickstart
<2015-05-05 Tue>
*** Send a reminder to the group
SCHEDULED: <2015-05-30 Thu>
```

Instead, I get this output, and I have to specify "Date" twice:

```
** Documenting with Sphinx: Beyond Quickstart
<2015-05-05 Tue>
*** Send a reminder to the group
Scheduled: <<2015-05-05 Tue> -5d>
```

So I guess I have two questions:

1. how can I "reuse" an already captured variable?
2. how can I modify the date? I saw an answer using `%(...)` and now can't find it again, and at any rate it didn't seem to accept arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the built in templates you can build your own via a function and pass this as the final argument to the capture template.  Then you can use arbitrary elisp to manipulate data.  Here is an example in your case, that uses `org-completing-read-no-i` for string prompts and `org-read-date` for date input.  I have updated it to show how to set a schedule on a date 5 days earlier (calculated as 3600 secs times 24 times 5):

```
(defun my-event-template ()
    "Capture template for events"
  (let* ((event (org-completing-read-no-i "Event: " nil))
         (date-input (org-read-date nil t nil "Date: "))
         (date (format-time-string 
                      (car org-time-stamp-formats)
                      date-input))
         (date+shift (concat (substring date 0 -1) " -5d" (substring date -1)))
         (date-schedule (format-time-string (car org-time-stamp-formats)
                                            (time-subtract date-input 
                                                           (seconds-to-time (* 3600 24 5))))))
  (format "** %s\n  %s\n*** Send a reminder to the group\n  DEADLINE: %s SCHEDULED: %s"
   event date date+shift date-schedule)))

(custom-set-variables
  '(org-capture-templates
    (quote
     (("m" "Meetup" entry (file+headline "~/org/STLPython.org" "events")
       (function my-event-template))))))
```

Typical output from this is

```
** My event
  <2015-03-29 Sun>
*** Send a reminder to the group
  DEADLINE: <2015-03-29 Sun -5d> SCHEDULED: <2015-03-24 Tue>
```

The object `(car org-time-stamp-formats)` is the standard format for an active timestamp.

Comment: nice! How would I *actually* shift the date though? I want it to be scheduled five days before instead of just a reminder on that day.

Comment: No problem - answer updated now with deadline set as your earlier schedule proposed, and with a relative scheduled date

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to a similar situation.
I create a headline for a candidate, which contains a property with today's date, and add a child headline with a deadline two days in the future from today.

Here is the portion of the capture template for the child headline:

```
*** %\\1                  :waitreply:sentrequest:
     DEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+2\"))
```

It took me longer than I care to admit to figure this out, but I'm happy with the solution.  org-read-date with these parameters produces an internal time value, which org-insert-time-stamp converts into a timestamp.