# Invoke Interactive Function From org-capture-templates

Tags: org-mode

I have a function called `create-org-link` that creates a file link based on an arbitrary string that I pass to it. I would like to be able to invoke this function when I invoke org capture.

Here's what I have tried:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("w" "Work Log" entry (file+headline "c:/td/gtd/org/WorkLogs.org" "Today") "** %(create-org-link) %?")
))
```

I know that the function works because I can use it outside of this template.
However, when I execute if from here I get the following output:

```
** %![Error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (title) Foobar de roobarb (interactive sPlease enter a title: ) (insert (format [[file:%s-%s.org][%s - %s]] (format-time-string org-link-date-stamp-format (current-time)) (replace-regexp-in-string    title) (format-time-string org-link-date-stamp-format (current-time)) title))) 0)]
```

Is there a different template element that I should be using?

*Edit* - 5/5/2014 @ 12:48

Here's the function that is being called:

```
(defun create-org-link (title)
  "Foobar de roobarb"
  (interactive "sPlease enter a title: ")
  (insert (format "[[file:%s-%s.org][%s - %s]]" (format-time-string org-link-date-stamp-format(current-time)) (replace-regexp-in-string " " "" title) (format-time-string org-link-date-stamp-format(current-time)) title)))

(defvar org-link-date-stamp-format "%y%m%d"
  "Format of date stamps to use in Org links")
```

Ha ha - I guess I should take out my placeholder comments before asking questions about it in a forum :-)

Comment: Have you tried `(call-interactively #'create-org-link)`?

Comment: Thanks Dan! I get this: byte-code: Capture abort: (wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil)

Comment: You don't show all of the code you are using. But clearly the lambda form you show (from the error msg) is not a function. You have 3 (unquoted) symbols after the argument list and before the `interactive` spec: `Foobar de roobarb`. See the definitions of a function, command, and lambda form. Probably you meant to put double quotes around `Foobar de roobarb`, to create a doc string.

Comment: This is probably best done by defining a function for the template where you can prompt for your link argument.  Cf. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10294/2710

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(defun create-org-link (&optional title)
  "Foobar de roobarb"
  (interactive)
  (unless title
    (setq title
          (read-string "Please enter a title: ")))
  (let ((out (format "[[file:%s-%s.org][%s - %s]]"
                     (format-time-string
                      org-link-date-stamp-format(current-time))
                     (replace-regexp-in-string " " "" title)
                     (format-time-string
                      org-link-date-stamp-format(current-time))
                     title)))
    (if (called-interactively-p)
        (insert out)
      out)))
```

Rather than prompt for the title as part of the interactive call, prompt for it manually if it wasn't passed.  `org-capture` doesn't default to `interactive` when calling the function.

Wrapping it as `(call-interactively #'create-org-link)` would work as well, however you will need to remove `insert` so that only the format call is passed.  Otherwise the data is inserted into the wrong buffer (as part of the prompt/parsing rather than passed to the final template).

The `if` statement at the end of the function takes care of inserting it (when interactive) vs returning the string (when called from the template).