# Using user prompted file name for org-capture in template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

With the help of [these](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/invoke-interactive-function-from-org-capture-templates?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902620/org-mode-how-do-i-create-a-new-file-with-org-capture), I managed to prompt the user for a file name in org-capture and combine it with a timestamp.

```
(defun my/generate-org-note-name ()
  (let ((name (read-string "Name: "))
        (time (format-time-string "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
    (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.org" time name) "~/org-wiki")))

(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("n" "note" plain 
     (file (my/generate-org-note-name))
     "#+TITLE: ")))
```

Now I would like to reuse this name and timestamp in the actual template.

- File name: `2018010101230456-myfile.org`
- Template:

  ```
  #+TITLE: my file
  #+STAMP: 2018010101230456
  ```

I am trying to return a list with file path and template from `my/generate-org-note-name` and then append it to the first 3 elements. But it looks like something (maybe my quoting) is wrong:

```
(defun my/generate-org-note-name ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (read-string "Name: "))
        (time (format-time-string "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
    (list (file (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.org" time name) "~/org-wiki")))
          (format "#+TITLE: %s\n#+STAMP: %s\n" name time))

(setq org-capture-templates
  '((apply #'append (list (list "n" "note" 'plain) (call-interactively
      #'my/generate-org-note-name)))))
```

The call to `apply` fails every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this via some dedicated variables.

```
(defun my/generate-org-note-name ()
  (setq my-org-note--name (read-string "Name: "))
  (setq my-org-note--time (format-time-string "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
  (expand-file-name (format "%s-%s.org" my-org-note--time my-org-note--name) "~/org-wiki"))

(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("n" "note" plain 
     (function my/generate-org-note-name)
     "%(format \"#+TITLE: %s\n#+STAMP: %s\n\" my-org-note--name my-org-note--time)")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! Somehow I thought I should avoid setting a "global" variable, but it doesn't seem to matter!

Comment: Would you know why the `%(format...` syntax is needed for the template? I tried to simply use `(format...` which seem to correctly return a string in the REPL but does not work when used directly in the `org-capture-templates`.

Comment: the `%` syntax is used by the org-capture parser to eval sexps inside `org-capture-templates`. You can refer to the `org-capture`'s source code.