# capture template for org-projectile?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, projectile, org-capture

Is there a way to define a capture template for `org-projectile/capture` (`SPC a o p`)? The default capture template creates a todo in root and I'd rather have it under Tasks (`/Project Name/Tasks/<the task>`)

Also another one for project specific meeting notes would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the variable `org-projectile-per-project-filepath`, which defaults to `TODOs.org` and the variable `org-projectile-capture-template`, which defaults to `* TODO %?\n`.

```
(setq org-projectile-per-project-filepath "Tasks/tasks.org")
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like there's only one template for projectile, right?

Comment: Seems like it. You can use org-mode capture templates if you need more specific capture templates. Check out [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/using-user-prompted-file-name-for-org-capture-in-template) and [this blog post](http://storax.github.io/blog/2016/05/02/org-capture-tricks/)

Comment: @NilsRiedemann maybe a little late, but I just realized `org-projectile-todo-entry` is a function that takes a bunch of arguments, so you can use that to specify multiple projectile templates.